# I want to use EtherPad (or a clone). My site is running Ruby on Rails. API or local install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scala, etherpad

I'd like to utilize an etherpad interface on my website.  Two questions:

1) is there any site with an etherpad api that I could just call remotely?
2) if not, how much trouble is it to install scala and have the two run concurrently?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why scala is relevant to this but see my answer below

Comment: oxbow_lakes: Probably it's relevant because parts of EtherPad are written in Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://piratepad.net and http://ietherpad.com

And you can embed those etherpad instances using a simple iframe as suggested here: http://etherpad.com/ep/blog/posts/embedding-etherpad

There doesn't seem to be a proper API yet for more robust interactions.

Comment: Note that the embedding-etherpad link has gone stale.  See the answer I just added.

Answer (score 2):

The original [etherpad.com](http://etherpad.com) has now gone away but at that link there is a list of clones.

The instructions for embedding etherpads seems to have gone away with the rest of etherpad.com but I believe it's as simple as this:

```
<div id="ep">
<iframe src="http://etherpad.com/foo?fullScreen=1"></iframe>
</div>
```

Replace "etherpad.com" with whatever clone you're using, "foo" with the name of your pad, and you may or may not want to change that fullScreen=1 to fullScreen=0 (or leave it off altogether).

Answer (score 1):

Installing scala might mean a few things:

- Installing the SDK (i.e. `scalac`)
- Installing the runtime

Assuming you mean the runtime, scala runs entirely on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) so assuming you have 1.5+ JVM installed, you can run scala programs on it easily (Scala just compiles down to bytecode, after all). All a scala program requires is a few JARs on the classpath (`scala-library` and `scala-compiler`)

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a better solution **Etherpad Lite** it is easily installable and embedable. See http://etherpad.org